# How to retrieve data with offset and limit using webservice request?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am trying to build an AX service to retrieve data from  InventTable in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009. 
With reference to https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/70476.aspx ,I tried  to execute a code in AOT Job for retrieving data with modifieddate="2/7/2013"
The code sample is as below:

```
    static void SelectQueryTest(Args _args)
    {
       Query q = new Query();
    QueryRun qr;
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
    int64 countItem;
    InventTable inventTable;
    Fromdate FromDate = 2\7\2013;


    ;

    qbds = q.addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));
    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(InventTable, modifiedDateTime)).value(date2StrUsr(FromDate ));
    qr = new QueryRun(q);
    countItem =SysQuery::countTotal(qr);
   if(countItem>0)
   {

     while(qr.next())
    {

        inventTable = qr.get(tableNum(inventTable));
        info(strfmt("Item Name: %1", inventTable.ItemName));
    }
   }
   else
   {
     info("No records found");
   }

    }
```

Can any one suggest me how to write a code which retrieves data using offset and limit that is taken from a webservice request.

Comment: What is offset, what is limit, what webservice? Your date as written is the second of July.

Comment: I actually meant a method like skip and take in linq or  a select query  like "SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 18 OFFSET 8" in MySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

limit and offset are not available in x++ when querying AX.

In my opinion you have 2 options to acheive the same goal.

1. Order your result set by recId, store the recId, and the use where recId > yourRecId for your offset. You would also need to count the records manually using something like while select.
2. Use x++ to query the SQL database directly, in which case you should be able to use any SQL supported by the server

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely do not need to make a service yourself, as there are standard ways to do it.

Take a look on the answers here: [Fetching data from dynamics ax 2009 using Ax webservices and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667013/fetching-data-from-dynamics-ax-2009-using-ax-webservices-and-c-sharp)

Also take a look on [this screencast](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/SanjayJain/Microsoft-Dynamics-AX-2009-AIF-Web-Services-Screencast).

Comment: Thanks for the response Jan .We have almost 2 hundred thousand products in  AX database.I think it will be difficult to fetch a huge set of data at a time using a webservice.So I am thinking of an AX service that retrieves only 500 data each and pull those into my MySql database